# Javascript: Fetch DELETE and PUT requests

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, http-delete, http-put

I have gotten outside of GET and POST methods with Fetch. But I couldn't find any good DELETE and PUT example.

So, I ask you for it. Could you give a good example of DELETE and PUT methods with fetch. And explain it a little bit.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Here is a fetch `POST` example. You can do the same for `DELETE`.

```
function createNewProfile(profile) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('first_name', profile.firstName);
    formData.append('last_name', profile.lastName);
    formData.append('email', profile.email);

    return fetch('http://example.com/api/v1/registration', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    }).then(response => response.json())
}

createNewProfile(profile)
   .then((json) => {
       // handle success
    })
   .catch(error => error);
```

Comment: So POST, PUT and DELETE are identical in syntax ?

Comment: The difference is that you will need the `id` of the record to DELETE or PUT.  It will now look like
      `return fetch('http://example.com/api/v1/registration/1', {`
          
             `method: 'PUT',`
          `body: formData`
      `})`

Comment: Why do we need Id of the record if it is not needed for the API?

Comment: 'Needing an id' is specific to the API. The point that _is_ always true is that with `PUT` and `DELETE` you are updating or deleting the resource _at_ the URI respectively. So if do a `DELETE` request on `/x`, I expect `/x` to be deleted after.

Comment: @Evert That's not always true. It completely depends on the server implementation. That's how the HTTP spec suggests servers should handle `DELETE` and `PUT` requests, but servers are implemented by humans who don't always follow the spec religiously.

Comment: @Nick replace 'religiously' with 'correctly' and I would agree with you. Of course people can do things incorrectly.  I think we can talk about what people should be doing without having to add the caveat that some people do things wrong.

Comment: @Evert Generally I agree, but a beginning programmer may not have enough understanding of the HTTP spec and how it relates to server implementation to realize that actual functionality is highly variable from one API to another. Better to suggest that `PUT`/`DELETE` *should* always update/delete rather than say that it *is always true* that they do as such. We're mincing words though, and I think whoever's reading this probably gets the point.

Answer (score 73):

Ok, here is an example of a fetch API `DELETE`, too:

```
fetch('https://example.com/delete-item/' + id, {
  method: 'DELETE',
})
.then(res => res.text()) // or res.json()
.then(res => console.log(res))
```

Comment: Note that there's no need to parse the result. Parsing res to text will return in an empty string, and parsing it to JSON will give a parsing error.

Comment: It is necessary to resolve promise, because first `res` is promise.

Answer (score 31):

For put method we have:

```
const putMethod = {
 method: 'PUT', // Method itself
 headers: {
  'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' // Indicates the content 
 },
 body: JSON.stringify(someData) // We send data in JSON format
}

// make the HTTP put request using fetch api
fetch(url, putMethod)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data)) // Manipulate the data retrieved back, if we want to do something with it
.catch(err => console.log(err)) // Do something with the error
```

Example for someData, we can have some input fields or whatever you need:

```
const someData = {
 title: document.querySelector(TitleInput).value,
 body: document.querySelector(BodyInput).value
}
```

And in our `data base` will have this in `json` format:

```
{
 "posts": [
   "id": 1,
   "title": "Some Title", // what we typed in the title input field
   "body": "Some Body", // what we typed in the body input field
 ]
}
```

For delete method we have:

```
const deleteMethod = {
 method: 'DELETE', // Method itself
 headers: {
  'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' // Indicates the content 
 },
 // No need to have body, because we don't send nothing to the server.
}
// Make the HTTP Delete call using fetch api
fetch(url, deleteMethod) 
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data)) // Manipulate the data retrieved back, if we want to do something with it
.catch(err => console.log(err)) // Do something with the error
```

In the url we need to type the id of the of deletion: `https://www.someapi/id`

Answer (score 9):

Just Simple Answer. 
FETCH DELETE

```js
function deleteData(item, url) {
  return fetch(url + '/' + item, {
    method: 'delete'
  })
  .then(response => response.json());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is good example of the CRUD operation using fetch API:

“A practical ES6 guide on how to perform HTTP requests using the Fetch API” by Dler Ari https://link.medium.com/4ZvwCordCW

Here is the sample code I tried for PATCH or PUT

```
function update(id, data){
  fetch(apiUrl + "/" + id, {
    method: 'PATCH',
    body: JSON.stringify({
     data
    })
  }).then((response) => {
    response.json().then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
  })
```

For DELETE:

```
function remove(id){
  fetch(apiUrl + "/" + id, {
    method: 'DELETE'
  }).then(() => {
     console.log('removed');
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
  });
```

For more info visit Using Fetch - Web APIs | MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch > Fetch_API.

Comment: Remember we're trying to write reference-quality content here; you shouldn't be adding "thanks" to everything, and definitely not emoji (unless the Q&A is actually about dealing with them, e.g. Unicode handling).

Answer (score 6):

Some examples:

```
async function loadItems() {
        try {
            let response = await fetch(`https://url/${AppID}`);
            let result = await response.json();
            return result;
        } catch (err) {
        }
    }

    async function addItem(item) {
        try {
            let response = await fetch("https://url", {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    AppId: appId,
                    Key: item,
                    Value: item,
                    someBoolean: false,
                }),
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            });
            let result = await response.json();
            return result;
        } catch (err) {
        }
    }

    async function removeItem(id) {
        try {
            let response = await fetch(`https://url/${id}`, {
                method: "DELETE",
            });
        } catch (err) {
        }
    }

    async function updateItem(item) {
        try {
            let response = await fetch(`https://url/${item.id}`, {
                method: "PUT",
                body: JSON.stringify(todo),
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            });
        } catch (err) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: mmm... really??? this doesn't make sense... why do you send the ID in the url and the rest of the data in the body? I've never seen such a PUT hit...

Answer (score 4):

Let me simplify this, you can straight up copy the code.

This is for PUT method :

```
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users', + id {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: 'user'
  })
})
.then(res => {
  return res.json()
})
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

and this is for DELETE :

```
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users' + id, {
  method: 'DELETE',
})
.then(res => {
  return res.json()
}) 
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

Note: I'm using dummy api here.

Comment: The ID is not necessary in the fetch if you are using it in the body section of the object you are stringifying.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me when using the PUT method. This method allows me to effectively update the 1st item using my first name:

```js
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users', {
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    id: 1,
    first_name: 'Anthony'
  })
})
.then(res => {
  return res.json()
})
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are examples for Delete and Put for React & redux & ReduxThunk with Firebase:

Update (PUT):

```
export const updateProduct = (id, title, description, imageUrl) => {
    await fetch(`https://FirebaseProjectName.firebaseio.com/products/${id}.json`, {
  method: "PATCH",
  header: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    title,
    description,
    imageUrl,
  }),
});

dispatch({
  type: "UPDATE_PRODUCT",
  pid: id,
  productData: {
    title,
    description,
    imageUrl,
  },
});
};
};
```

Delete:

```
export const deleteProduct = (ProductId) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
await fetch(
  `https://FirebaseProjectName.firebaseio.com/products/${ProductId}.json`,
  {
    method: "DELETE",
  }
);
dispatch({
  type: "DELETE_PRODUCT",
  pid: ProductId,
});
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const DeleteBtn = (id) => {

    fetch(`http://localhost:8000/blogs/${id}`, {
        method: "DELETE"
    })
        .then(() => {
            navigate('/');
        });

}
<button onClick={(event) => { DeleteBtn(blog.id)} }>delete</button>
```