# How can I update on reactjs fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net, fetch-api

I'm trying to update my table row however it is not working the profile part is not reading the data inside the input.

This is the function I use for the update button:

```
 handleUpdate(id, name, address,department){ 
      debugger
       jQuery.support.cors = true;
        function createNewProfile(profile) {
          
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('Employee_Name', profile.name);
    formData.append('Address', profile.address);
    formData.append('department', profile.depatment);
    return fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/PutEmployeeDetail/' +id, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
}

  createNewProfile(profile)
   .then((json) => {
       // handle success
    })
   .catch(error => error);
}
```

this is the part where is the form the input and the button

```
<div className="modal fade" id="UpdateEmployee" role="dialog">
         <div className="modal-dialog">
           <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 className="modal-title">Update Employee</h4>
          </div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleUpdate}> 
            <div className="container"> 
            <div className="modal-body"> 
            <table> 
            <tbody> 
            <tr> 
            <td>Name</td> 
            <td> 
            <input  type="text" 
                    name="Employee_Name"
                    value={this.state.Employee_Name} 
                    onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}/> 
           
            </td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
            <td>Address</td> 
            <td> 
            <input  type="text" 
                    name="Address" 
                    value={this.state.Address} 
                    onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}/> 
            </td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
            <td>Department</td> 
            <td> 
            <input  type="text" 
                    name='Department' 
                    value={this.state.Department} 
                    onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}/> 
            
            </td> 
            </tr> 
            </tbody> 
            </table> 
            </div> 
            </div> 
            <div className="modal-footer"> 
            <input type="submit" className="btn btn-info" onClick = { this.handleUpdate.bind(this,  this.state.Employee_ID , this.state.Employee_Name ,this.state.Address ,this.state.Department)} value =" Add Employee"/> 
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> 
            </div> 
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I see a typo - HandleUpdate and it's getting called like this - handleUpdate can you check that ?

Comment: oh wait i forgot to edit that part but i have changed that part already on the code

Comment: And you can only write this  - this.handleUpdate.bind(this) and you can access other things using this.state.name, no need to pass them

Comment: how i tried that but i also had an inputs for add new employee on the same pge that's why it make things difficult for it to read

Comment: got it and why do you have one function inside another and from where are you getting profile value ? it's confusing

Comment: because i need to pass the whole form inside the api.. and i use this as reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284338/react-fetch-delete-and-put-requests