# Enabling PUT DELETE methods in local WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("[action]/")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
    {
        return Ok(await _employeeService.GetAllEmployees());
    }
    [HttpDelete("[action]/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        await _employeeService.DeleteEmployee(id);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Through Swagger, everything works great, all requests are detected. But if you enter a direct request, in my case: https://localhost:7080/Employee/Delete/3, then 405 is returned. I read on the Internet, I met a situation, only with deployed APIs, but it doesn’t even work for me on a local host. What could be missing?

EDIT
Also trying to use it in TypeScript like this:

```
async function deleteById(url: string, id: number) {
    return await fetch(url + id.toString(), { method: 'DELETE', }).then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok)
            console.log(response);
        else
            return response.json();
    });
}
deleteById("https://localhost:7080/Employee/Delete/", id).then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
    });
```

And here is what i get...
[image]

Comment: By direct request, do you mean just entering "https://localhost:7080/Employee/Delete/3" in a browser? Because that will still just make a GET request. To really test PUT, DELETE, etc you should use a tool like Postman.

Comment: where are you entering this request? in the browser? you need something like postman, browser will send a get request to your method resulting in the 405

Comment: im using both browser and web page with typescript and sending request via fetch function

Comment: Your backend code is fine.  it's the way you're using the fetch API.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284338/javascript-fetch-delete-and-put-requests

Comment: In your screenshot you can see in the red line first word it say is "GET". You are sending a GET http request instead of a DELETE http request.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
  <modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Also you can check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440277/how-do-i-enable-http-put-and-delete-for-asp-net-mvc-in-iis)